# JSON and LINQ Query

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to parse the JSON file shown below, and get the coordinates of the place with specific name:

```
{"Theaters":[{"TheaterName":"Name1","GPSLocation":"3.888689,35.519845"},{"TheaterName":"Name2","GPSLocation":"33.867444,3.527002"},{"TheaterName":"Name3","GPSLocation":"33.897403,3.563645"},{"TheaterName":"Name4","GPSLocation":"34.438693, 3.831660"},{"TheaterName":"Name5","GPSLocation":"3.88392,35.48333"},{"TheaterName":"Name6","GPSLocation":"33.88424,35.483145"},{"TheaterName":"Name7","GPSLocation":"33.972802, 3.610099"},{"TheaterName":"Name8","GPSLocation":"33.857193,35.526886"},
{"TheaterName":"Name9","GPSLocation":"3.36394,35.735929"},{"TheaterName":"Name10","GPSLocation":"3.897403,35.563645"},{"TheaterName":"Name11","GPSLocation":"33.886605,3.508580"},{"TheaterName":"Name12","GPSLocation":"33.892134,3.517423"},
{"TheaterName":"Name13","GPSLocation":"3.917253,35.589074"},{"TheaterName":"Name14","GPSLocation":"33.2860,35.6115"}]}
```

The query i'm using is shown below, however the response is that expression couldn't be evaluated. What is the problem??  Thanks

```
var coordinates = from p in JSON["Theaters"].Children()
                                  where p["TheaterName"].Value<string>() == Name1
                                  select p["GPSLocation"].Values();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't you want the following?

```
var coordinates = from p in JSON["Theaters"].Children()
    where p["TheaterName"].Value<string>() == Name1
    select p["GPSLocation"].Value<string>();
```

After all, your GPSLocation is a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

The you sett this response? In Visual Studio debugger? If so you'll seee the defered execution of LINQ queries. They get executed on the first access or you call the extension methos ToList(), ToArray() etc.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get what you mean exactly, can you explain plz.

Comment: If you hover other a variable/property or something in Visual Studio during debugging you often see the message "expression couldn't evaluated" - mostly because of the lazy executon nature of LINQ expressions (they get executed on first access).
I only want to make sure if you mean this or something else.

Comment: No, you're correct. I am checking it in the debug mode and i get the following reply as you said.

Comment: You can add a ToList() or something like this to force execution and have a good debug experience.